# what is a wrap panel in windows 8 metro app context

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, wrappanel

I just wrote an "hello world" in windows 8 app and today I read some thing about wrap panel in a blog.

What is a *wrap panel*? When should it be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrappanels are used if your program is resizable to order the controls inside this panel.
I think that each item gets sizes based on the dimensions of the first item.
I guess it is very useful if your app should support snap view